# Returning an alternative value if a string is not found in a string-returning method

Tags: c#, string, return

I have a method which returns a string. It can be in normal operating conditions that a blank string or null is returned. However, is it a good coding practise to return `null` or `""` from this method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, in that situations I prefer returning `null` to show that string is not found. Empty string has usually used for showing empty result.

Alternative way is to throw some `Exception`, but as programmer I don't find usable to work with Exceptions. Returning `null` is **much better**.

Comment: Yes, and besides, because of the overhead of throwing exceptions, they should not be used to communicate for normal operation.

Comment: Yes - it's not appropriate to raise an exception for an expected result.  Returning a flag value is much easier and clearer than the alternative of changing everything to return a 'success' bool/enum and passing a string ref parameter.

Comment: @uosef: Overhead should be one of the last thoughts when deciding about whether to use exceptions or not (premature optimization is as evil as is premature pessimization, write clean code by default) (this is btw especially true in C++, where exceptions can be implemented almost overhead-free)

Comment: @mesiesta: `Returning null is much better.` is that w.r.t. the question, or a general rule?

Comment: @phresnel: For me it's a rule... Throw exceptions only in that situations where I can't find better and simplier solution.

Comment: @mesiesta: That rule is imho too blanket. My personal rule: Handle "expections" with normal control flow (i.e. return NULL or some nullable), handle exceptions (which are often programmer errors where checking preconditions have been forgotten) with exceptions.

Comment: Null will work well as long as it's the documented standard. I don't really want to end up littering my code with null checks and introduce a bug with a forgotten null check. Or am I thinking wrong?

Answer (score 1):

There is a semantic difference between `null` and the empty string. One says "it is not defined for that input", the other says "the correct value for that input is the empty string".

Imagine you have written a compiler for a subset of C that allows for a `main`-function that returns nothing. Your compiler returns a string with some fantasy assembly language.

```
// Testcode 0
void main() {
```

For this you would return `null`, the code is not well-formed because of the missing closing brace (no, do not throw an exception, errors in user written code are expected). There is no valid output.

```
// Testcode 1
void main() { printf("hello!"); }
```

For this you would return `"push 'hello!'\ncall printf"`

```
// Testcode 2
void main() {}
```

For this you might return `""`, the code does nothing and returns nothing, but is valid.

Answer (score 1):

The value `null` would be typically used for when "there is no string" (a string has "not been found" somewhere), or simply, no string applies. The empty string is more typically used for situations in which there is a string, but it is actually empty.

For example, if you search for some user's profile description in StackOverflow, an empty string would be a correct result if the user has not entered any profile description; and `null`, if no such user has been found.

Answer (score 1):

Yes I think so, (if you're expecting a string result from the method), but if not (e.g. an error/warning) I would consider the alternative of throwing an exception in your method. I usually use this approach instead of returning strings in this context.

e.g.

```
try
{
     Validate();
}
catch(NotValidException ex)
{
    // Report
}
```

The exception if not caught here will bubble up and be *less* silent than, for example, forgetting to check the return value of the Validate method.

Comment: But this should probably not be used when it would be common to not find the target string - such as a cache miss - due the overhead of throwing exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the method purpose, if you had a method `string GetCustomerName(int custId)` you would rather want to throw exception if customer doesn't exist as opposed to returning `null`.  From the other hand if had a method which changes the first letter of a string to be upper case and you provided `null` in the input, returning `null` would be acceptable.